# the number of inversions in the permutation "reverse"

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

Known, that number of inversions is $k$ in permutation: 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  ...&  n& \\ 
 a_1&  ...&  a_n& 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find number of inversions in permutation (let's call it "reverse"): 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  ...&  n& \\ 
 a_n&  ...&  a_1& 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

First, max number of inversions is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Then we can see if we get permutation with $0$ inversions than "reverse" permutation for it will have $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

I can guess that for $\sigma(i)$, $\sigma(n-i+1)$ sum of inversions in them is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Thus, answer will be $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-k$

Please help me to prove that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you define an inversion of $a$ as a pair of indices $i<j$ such that $a_i>a_j$, you can easily show that $(i,j)$ with $i<j$ is an inversion of $a$ if and only if $(n+1-j,n+1-i)$ is *not* an inversion of the reverse of $a$. The pair of *values* at those indices are the same in both cases, so if you define an inversion to be the (inverted) pair of values $\{a_i,a_j\}$ then it is even easier: the set of inversions of the reverse of $a$ is the complement of the set of inversions of$~a$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints.*

- Think of some permutation $ι$ on $[n]$ so that for any permutation $σ$ on $[n]$, “$σ$-reverse” is $σι$.
- An inversion of any permutation $σ$ on $[n]$ is a pair $(i,j)$ with $i < j$ such that $\frac{σ(i) - σ(j)}{i-j} < 0$.
- For permutations $σ$, $τ$ on $[n]$ you have $\frac{(στ)(i) - (στ)(j)}{i - j} = \frac{σ(τ(i)) - σ(τ(j))}{τ(i) - τ(j)}·\frac{τ(i) - τ(j)}{i - j}$.
- What does this imply for the inversions of $στ$ in terms of the inversions of $σ$ and $τ$?
- How many inversions does $ι$ have?